# Updating multiple columns in PostgreSQL using Knex.js

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I am trying to update multiple columns within a table using Knex.js

I have tried looking at suggestions in the Knex docs as well as online, but so far have not found any working solution.

My coding attempt:

```
const userUpdateHandler = (req,res,database)=>{
  const { id } = req.params;
  const { name, age } = req.body.formInput
  database('users')
  .where({ id })
  .update({ name }).update({ age})
  .then(resp => {
    if (resp) {
      res.json("success")
    } else {
      res.status(400).json('Not found')
    }
  })
  .catch(err => res.status(400).json('error updating user'))

}
```

The above is something I've tried out of sheer desperation, but what I would like it to do is to update multiple columns at once. 
Could you please advise me on the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

That should work https://runkit.com/embed/6ulv4hy93fcj

```
knex('table').update({foo: 1}).update({bar: 2}).toSQL()

// generates SQL: update "table" set "foo" = ?, "bar" = ?
```

and so should:

```
database('users')
  .where({ id })
  .update({ name, age })
```

Check out if your generated queries are what you are expecting...